# How to get the difference from dyanamically added fields- react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to Reactjs. All I'm trying to do is as follow:

I've three fields: ENTRY, EXIT, TOTAL

> TOTAL = EXIT - ENTRY

Example:

**ENTRY | EXIT | Total**

1 | 2 | 1

2 | 4 | 2

3 | 6 | 3

5 | 10| 5

Here ENTRY and EXIT are dynamically added fields when +Add button is clicked. I've been able to add the fields dynamically, but I am not getting the **TOTAL** value.

```
var entry;
var exit;
class Calculator extends React.Component {
      state = {
      values: [{id:0,exit:0,entry:0}],
      total:[]
 };

  add() {
    this.setState(prevState => prevState.values.push(null));
  }
  changeVal(val, index, key) {
    if(key == 'exit'){
      exit = val;
    }else{
      entry =val;
    }
     this.setState(prevState => (prevState.values[index] = {id:index, exit:val, entry: val}));
   }
  getTotal() {
    let total = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.state.values.length; i++) {
      if (this.state.values[i] !== null) {
        total = this.state.values[i].exit - this.state.values[i].entry;
      }
    }
    return total;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.values.map((val, index, key) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <input
              onChange={e => this.changeVal(e.target.value, index, 'exit')}
              name={ `exit[${index}]` }
              type="number"
              value={val}
              placeholder="Enter a value"
            />
            <input
              onChange={e => this.changeVal(e.target.value, index, 'entry')}
              name={ `entry[${index}]` }
              type="number"
              value={val}
              placeholder="Enter a value"
            />
            <input
              name={ `total[${index}]` }
              type="number"
              value={this.state.total}
            />
         </div>
        ))}
         <button onClick={this.add.bind(this)}> +Add</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Calculator /> , document.getElementById('calculator'));
```

Also please tell me if it is the best approach to add input fields dynamically. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```js
var entry;
var exit;
class Calculator extends React.Component {
  state = {
    values: [{ id: 0, exit: 0, entry: 0 }],
    total: []
  };

  add() {
    let { values } = this.state;
    values.push({ id: 0, exit: 0, entry: 0 });
    this.setState({ values });
  }

  changeVal(val, index, key) {
    let { values } = this.state;
    values[index][key] = val;
    this.setState({ values });
  }

  getTotal(data) {
    return Number(data.exit) - Number(data.entry);
  }

  render() {
    let { values, total } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {values.map((val, index, key) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <input
                onChange={e => this.changeVal(e.target.value, index, "exit")}
                name={`exit[${index}]`}
                type="number"
                value={val.exit}
                placeholder="Enter a value"
              />
              <input
                onChange={e => this.changeVal(e.target.value, index, "entry")}
                name={`entry[${index}]`}
                type="number"
                value={val.entry}
                placeholder="Enter a value"
              />
              <input
                name={`total[${index}]`}
                type="number"
                value={this.getTotal(val)}
              />
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <button onClick={this.add.bind(this)}> +Add</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the live [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KbRXMW?editors=0010)

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

There are few place where your code misbehaves.

```
<input
          onChange={e => this.changeVal(e.target.value, index, 'exit')}
          name={ `exit[${index}]` }
          type="number"
          value={val.exit}
          placeholder="Enter a value"
        />
```

You have given entire object to value instead you to should give property (val.exit).

While adding you need to push an object to value array.

```
add() {
this.setState(prevState => prevState.values.push({id:this.state.values.length,exit:0,entry:0}));}
```

while changing values, you need to change the value for specific property.

```
changeVal(val, index, key) {
if(key == 'exit'){
  exit = val;
}else{
  entry =val;
}

var changeVal = this.state.values[index] || {id:index, exit:0, entry: 0};
changeVal[key] = val;
 this.setState(prevState => ( prevState.values[index] = changeVal));}
```

For total, you need to call the getTotal function.

```
<input
          name={ `total[${index}]` }
          type="number"
          value={this.getTotal(index)}
        />
```

Here is a live [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-227fyq).